# (Python) How can I turn a csv file with thousands of 10 digit numbers into decimal? (10dig -> 3dig+7decimal)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am working with large data of GPS coordinates. These coordinates are coming in as 10 digit numbers (`1234567890`) from a csv file.

I have two 25,000 columns of 10 digit numbers for both Latitude and Longitude.

How can I turn `1234567890` into `123.4567890`?

I've looked at different ways to manipulate and extract strings, but am confused on how to make Python add a value a certain amount of spaces forward.

Thanks,

Comment: So You are looking for a way to turn 1234567890 into 123.4567890?

Comment: Just convert the 10 digit numbers from the CSV file to integers and divide them by 10000000.

Comment: Thanks guys. I realized that I'm an idiot when I went to bed and realized I can do basic math to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if your content is string and you need to divide by `10**7`, you could simply do this:

```
def to_float(s):
    return float(s)/10**7
```

then do `df.apply(to_float)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the csv file itself (instead of the in-memory data read from the csv file), you could use the regular expression library.

```
import re

with open('input.csv') as input_file, open('output.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    for line in input_file:
        line = re.sub(r'(\d{3})(\d{7})', r'\1.\2', line)
        output_file.write(line)
```